# Django HTML, how to pass radio option select via AJAX and load form

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, forms

how to pass value selected from radio button to ajax url. 
I have radio button select download/upload. 
**CODE:**

```
  <form id="listofiles" action="" class="post-form" role=form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  Select: Download:
  <input class="form-check-input" name="optionsRadios" type="radio" value="download">
  or Upload:
  <input class="form-check-input" name="optionsRadios" type="radio" value="upload">
  BUTTON: 
  <input type="submit" value="GO" id="download" name="download" class="btn btn-info" />
  <input type="submit" value="GO" id="upload"  name="upload" class="btn btn-warning" />
```

Based on which one is select button will show. 
CODE:

```
<script>
$("input[name='optionsRadios']:radio")
  .change(function() {
    $("#upload").toggle($(this).val() == "upload");
    $("#download").toggle($(this).val() == "download"); });
</script>
```

Once the user selects the options, it will load the data from the other HTML file into div
CODE:

```
<div id="fetchdata" align="center">
  <!-- LOADING DATA FROM THE AJAX listofiles.html -->
</div>
```

AJAX CODE:

```
$("#listofiles").submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
$.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
    url: 'listofiles.html',
    type: $(this).attr('GET'),
    data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
    success: function(data) { // on success..
        $("#fetchdata").html(data); // update the DIV
        console.log(data);
    }
});
return false;
});
```

HTML: listofiles.html 
Issue, in this page, I have two forms with the different ID. How to load forms based on the optionsRadios selected.

CODE:

```
   <div id="download" style="display:none"><div align="center" class="container">
   <form id="download" action="download" role=form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
   . . . 
   <div class="col" align="left">
     <button type="submit" name="download" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">DOWNLOAD</button>
   </div></div></form></div></div>

   <div id="upload" style="display:none"><div align="center" class="container">
   <form id="upload" action="upload" role=form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
   . . . 
   <div class="col" align="left">
     <button type="submit" name="upload" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">UPLOAD</button>
   </div></div></form></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that we stay on the same page: then we can update your code:

Reuse the same selector:

```
$("input[name='optionsRadios']:radio:checked").val() == "upload");
```

Use the `checked` pseudoselector to see which value was selected to toggle the correct div.

> Executing this code will result in multiple elements with the same id name. Better to use class names or unique ids.

```
$("#listofiles").submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
$.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
    url: 'listofiles.html',
    type: $(this).attr('GET'),
    data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
    success: function(data) { // on success..
        $("#fetchdata").html(data); // update the DIV
        $("div[id='upload']").toggle($("input[name='optionsRadios']:radio:checked").val() == "upload");
        $("div[id='download']").toggle($("input[name='optionsRadios']:radio:checked").val() == "download");  
//there is already another element with id download | you need to change that, so circumventing like this for now.
        }
    }
});
return false;
});
```